# How to merge HTML files into one file with PHP?

Tags: php, html

I was wondering if it's possible to merge a bunch of HTML files into one file, dynamically, when a user clicks a link?  Let's say we have the following files in `/files`

```
1.html
2.html
3.html
4.html
```

When a user clicks a link, it takes all of those files and creates a new file that has all of their HTML content merged (but it doesn't delete the originals) using PHP.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Note that you'll want to be careful with the html that you get as a result of this, considering that generally html blocks will have header and meta elements that might get repeated by simple concatenation.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php

readfile('1.html');
readfile('2.html');
readfile('3.html');
readfile('4.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

To simply output the files after they have been merged you can use:

```
chdir("./files/");
print join(array_map("file_get_contents",
                     array("1.html", "2.html", "3.html", "4.html")));
```

I guess you didn't mean a static list though. To have a complete directory `/files` read you can adapt this to:

```
print join(array_map("file_get_contents", glob("files/*.html")));
```

If your question was really about creating a new file from the combined contents, then replace the `print` with `file_put_contents(..., "5.html")` for example.